# bitmap image share via email without Uri

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm using a library that returns a bitmap image if I want to share this image to another application or send it via email?  I don't have the Uri of the image then what should I do

Comment: You have to store it first after that you can share it in any application.

Answer (score 0):

1. convert your bitmap into a file:

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(path + "/image_name.jpg"); 
            OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // saving the Bitmap to a file compressed as a JPEG with 85% compression rate
            fOut.flush(); // Not really required
            fOut.close(); // do not forget to close the stream
```

2. Get the URI from the file: 
   `Uri yourUri = Uri.fromFile(file);`

Addition: for android 7.0+ you need [a different way to get URI from file](https://medium.com/@sauge16/targetting-sdkversion-24-android-nougat-and-above-and-sharing-file-through-intent-3f0f0128fa7e).
Saving file to the default main directory is only an example but maybe not the best practice.

Comment: This will not work on Android 7.0+, as you cannot share a `file` `Uri`. Also, putting things in the root of external storage is very inappropriate -- this is why Android Q/R are basically eliminating your solution.

Comment: @CommonsWare added in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your environment:
- you can get hand over the complete image (e.g. an attachment in an email)
- if you have an solution which could be accessed from the target, then you can create your own uri. On a local system, you could store the image in a file. Or if you have a web application, you might want to make the image available so that you can provide an url to the image, too)

So it mainly depends on the whole Szenario: where does the image come from, how big is it? What is the target? ....

And sorry, that I do Not write this as a comment - need a reputation of 50 to write comments first ....

Comment: The environment is Android, as is indicated by the question tags.

Comment: Ohh, right. Missed that completely. Thank you. Will have a closer look at all tags in the future.